# AngularJS animate save button

Tags: angularjs, animation

I have a Save button and if it is clicked, a flag is set to true in my controller. 
What I want to do now is that the save button should become a different color for a few seconds and than go back to the original color.

Is there a simple solution to do this - in the way that if the flag become true than set it to false after 3 seconds or so.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far. Also you can use ng-class to add class and set a timeout to reset the flag after delay

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-class` and `$timeout` together to have that effect

Answer (score 0):

You have clearly stated what should be done. It is very easy.

Like @Rajesh and @Shashank suggested, ng-class would be the best option.

Since you need the animation for a Save functionality, I think you **should not go for timeout.**

1. Just define a two styles for the Save button. For ex: *Save* and
   *Saving...*
2. Create a flag and keep it as false at the initial stage.
3. ng-class should be *Save* when the flag is false and *Saving...*
   when true.
4. Once the Button is clicked, make the flag true.
5. After the completion of Save operation, make the flag true false
   again.

There, you are done.

**Note:** Don't forget to make the flag false in the error handling area too.